# Checking upper case in AWK with range [A-Z] not working

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have the following bash script:

```
cat test | awk '/^[A-Z]/ {print NF}'
```

Let's assume the content of test is the following:

```
This one yes
this one no
This one yes
this one no
```

In principle it should print the number of fields of first and third line, since I'm looking for lines beginning with a character in upper case. However, the result is that number of fields of all the lines in the file is printed.
If I try with grep, with the same regular expression, the result is what I expect.

In addition, if instead of putting [A-Z], I write [[:upper:]] the script works flawlessly.

My question is: why in the first case it does not work?

Comment: It might vary on the awk version you are using. It works fine on my `mawk 1.3.3`. Also, note it is not necessary to use `cat file | awk ...`. Instead, you can use `awk ... file`. Also, `[[:upper:]]` is POSIX, as read in http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC27

Comment: gawk 3.1.8 returns four lines. If I change the regex to `/^T/`, it works as expected.

Comment: Works as expected in `gawk 4.0.1` and `mawk 1.2`

Comment: Looks like a (fixed) bug in gawk to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your locale setting. Google locale. Set LC_ALL=C to get a common one but using character classes is the right approach.

Comment: That's probably not the root cause. On my box, gawk 3.1.8 shows the OP's behavior; gawk 4.0.1 shows the expected behavior.

Comment: Maybe one uses the locale setting and the other doesn't?

Comment: Could be. Can OP test with `$ LC_ALL=C cat test | awk ...`?

Comment: ITYM `$ LC_ALL=C awk '...' test`. It's maybe worth noting that locale's don't work properly (at all?) on cygwin at least so which platform the OPs running on could be a factor too. Either way, it's just one more gotcha in support of using character classes.

Comment: Ok with LC_ALL=C it works, but why doesn't it without? I mean the regular expression is correct. Could it be possible that [A-Z] is interpreted as AaBbCc...Zz by AWK? This is the only reason I can think of.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it can mean. or `aAbB...zZ` or any of several other variations. That's part of what your locale defines - the order of characters. With LC_ALL=C you get `ab...zAB...Z` (or the other way around, I don't remember and it doesn't matter). But in the end - just use character classes as resolving these types of issue are exactly why they exist.

Comment: So is locale something that's usually hardset in a program like `awk` that needs some specific regex parsing?

Comment: I think each tool probably has it's own rules for character ordering if it can't determine a specific locale, and it's entirely possible those rules could change from release to release since they're arbitrary anyway (who's to say that `a..zA..Z` is more "right" than `aA...zZ` or any other ordering?). If you use explicit character ranges like `[A-Z]` then you're simply asking for trouble.